# Multiple modal buttons for different sources

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have seen answers for this but I still cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I know the **ids** must be unique but all the answers so far are not quite the same problem. I'm new to JQuery so this is something new Im still learning.

The problem I am experiencing is I cant get the Modal windows to pop up to the designated button. I can 1 to work but not all 3.

I feel like Im close to figuring this out, just at the point of throwing my hands up!

Here is my HTML:

```
                        <div class="col-md-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
                           <div class="hovereffect">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src='images/pollution.jpg' alt="" >
                              <div class="overlay">
                                 <h2>Environmental Contamination in Horseshoe Crabs</h2>
                                 <button id="myBtn1">Content Coming Soon</button> 
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
                           <div class="hovereffect">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src='images/horseshoecrab1.jpg' alt="" >
                              <div class="overlay">
                                 <h2>Maternal Transfer of Contaminants in Horseshoe Crabs</h2>
                                 <button id="myBtn2">Content Coming Soon</button> 
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInRight">
                           <div class="hovereffect">
                              <img class="img-responsive" src='images/cichlid.jpg' alt="" >
                              <div class="overlay">
                                 <h2>Mate Choice in Convict Cichlids</h2>
                                 <button id="myBtn3">Content Coming Soon</button> 
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
.....
                     <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                           <span class="close">&times;</span>
                           <p>Environmental coming soon.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                           <span class="close">&times;</span>
                           <p>Maternal description coming soon.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
                        <!-- Modal content -->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                           <span class="close">&times;</span>
                           <p>Mate choice cotent coming soon.</p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

The `class="modal"` only refers to CSS styling so I did not include it as I dont think its important. That said, I could be very wrong. Be more than happy to share too.

My JS

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal1");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal3");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the variables `btn` and `modal` and redeclaring them twice to be other elements. This won't work. Instead, you can do the following: Declare a `click()` function for all buttons with an `id` starting with "myBtn" using `^=` and get the referenced modal with `substr()`. For the `<span>` elements with the class `close`, just declare a function for all 3 of them based on the class and close the closest modal. You can simply use `show()` and `hide()` instead of setting the style attribute `hidden` to `none`.

```
 $("button[id^='myBtn']").on("click", function() {
    let selected = $(this).attr("id").substr(5);
    $("#myModal" + selected).show();
 });

 $(".close").on("click", function() {
   $(this).closest(".modal").hide();
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This does make sense though, I just found an easier method. Sometimes you have to get up and just walk away to see it.